# textarea should get copy to another textarea and original textarea should be cleared on a button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code.

It displays two `textarea`s where the text from one `textarea` gets copied to another `textarea` on a button click using JavaScript

```js
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayOut(){
var input=document.getElementById("txt").value;
var text2=document.getElementById("txt1");
text2.value=input;
if(input.length===0)
{
 alert("Please enter a valid input");
 return;
}
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}
}
 

</script>
</head>
```

```html
<body>
<h1 id="result">Javascript Exm</h1>



<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50"  onclick="eraseText()"></textarea><input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">


</body>
```

I want to accomplish the following:

1)On button click the text should get copied to another `textarea` and the text from origial `textarea` ie. first `textarea` should get clear to accept  other text, so i have an erase function but it doesn't work.

2) I want to display  the text should get copied in second `textarea` in a continuous format one below the other on a button click.

Comment: so you want to create a new text area each time your copy the text?

Comment: Your code throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: displayOut is not defined` in the console

Comment: Then you might want to add some button elements to click. Currently you've `eraseText` attached to textarea's click event, which might not offer great user experience.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You seemed to have declared EraseText as a function but not actually called it. Adding the "\n" gives the line breaks in text2.

```js
function displayOut(){
  var input=document.getElementById("txt").value;
  if(input.length===0)
  {
      alert("Please enter a valid input");
      return;
  }

  var text2=document.getElementById("txt1");
  text2.value += input+"\n";
  eraseText();
  
}
  function eraseText() {
      document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50"  onclick="eraseText()"></textarea><input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">
```

Comment: the code wrks it was really too easy

Comment: thnks Simon H,    itz wrkng similar hw i'd thought of

Answer (score 0):

> 1)on a button click the text should get copied to another textarea and the text from origial textare ie. first textarea should get clear to accept the another text, so i hv use erase function bt it doesn't work and second is that
>
> 2) and i want to display that the text should gets copied in second textarea in a continuous format one below the other on a button click.

```
try the below code
```

```
<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="10" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="10"  onclick="eraseText()"></textarea>    <input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">
<script >

function displayOut(){
var input=document.getElementById("txt").value;
var text2=document.getElementById("txt1");

if(input.length===0)
{
    alert("Please enter a valid input");
    return;
}
  else
text2.value+=input+'\n';
eraseText();

}
function eraseText() 
document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}
</script>
```

fiddle -->http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/m740vwet/1/