# text from one textarea should get copy to another textarea and original textarea should be cleared on a button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have done with following code it displays two textarea where the text from one textarea gets copied to another textarea on a button click using javascript

```js
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayOut(){
var input=document.getElementById("txt").value;
var text2=document.getElementById("txt1");
text2.value=input;
if(input.length===0)
{
 alert("Please enter a valid input");
 return;
}
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<h1 id="result">Javascript Exm</h1>
<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly" ></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50"  onclick="eraseText()"></textarea>
  <input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">
</body>
```

but I need that:

1. On a button click the text should get copied to another textarea and the text from original text area ie. first textarea should get clear to accept the other text, so I have use erase function bt it doesn't work and second is that
2. I want to display that the text should gets copied in second textarea in a continuous format one below the other on a button click.

Comment: remove the eraseText function outside of displayout function

Comment: @sana how many times will ask the same question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146990/textarea-should-get-copy-to-another-textarea-and-original-textarea-should-be-cle/32147255#32147255

Comment: So? This is not a "I want" place.. your question is very lazy.  Do it yourself, it is very simple - are you unable to do even the most basic of tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}

function displayOut() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById("txt1");
    text2.value = input;
    if (input.length === 0) {
        alert("Please enter a valid input");
        return;
    }
    eraseText();

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/840/

You should move `eraseText()` out of `displayOut`and then call it inside `displayOut`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, you did little mistake , your `eraseText()` move out from `displayOut()`. and call `eraseText()`function after copied text in second textarea.

```js
function displayOut() {
  var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var text2 = document.getElementById("txt1");
  text2.value = input;
  if (input.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter a valid input");
    return;
  }
  eraseText(); //call  function to erase text in textarea.

}

function eraseText() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result">Javascript Exm</h1>

<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50" onclick="eraseText()"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayOut(){
    var input=document.getElementById("txt").value;

    if(input.length===0)
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid input");
        return;
    }else{
       var text2=document.getElementById("txt1");
       text2.value=input;
       eraseText();
    }
}
function eraseText()
{
    document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}
```